# Is there a CMS that will give you 100/100 pagespeed out of the box?

Tags: web-development, html, cms, web, quality-assurance

Google shows a lot of stuff about how to improve [pagespeed score](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), but I have been unable to find any CMS (Content Management System) be it proprietary, open source or even a Page Builder that claims to offer 100/100 pagespeed (or something close to it) out of the box which seems weird to me, since these metrics are nowadays considered to be a measure of quality, regardless of statements from google suggesting that they shouldn't be so.

**So, can you list a one or a few CMS-like projects offering 100/100 or so pagespeed scores out of the box?**

In case you're unsure about the "out-of-the-box" term, that means in this case, that as soon as you install the platform (or create a new page), without adding any code or complex configurations, you can create a content page with it's own URL, you can paste that URL in Google's Pagespeed test and it will score 100/100 (and show your content on that URL as expected for any CMS).

Here is the link to the pagespeed test page just to be clear of what I am asking here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've found Google to favour the quality of the content over the "speed" of the content, but even with that being said it is still a criterion for the rank of your page.

I'd always used **WordPress** and a suitable caching manager (like WPRocket) that can generate static sites, which are always blazing fast compared to dynamically-generated content, especially on lower end hardware. One thing to keep in mind is also the themes that you use, and to achieve a perfect PageSpeed score, you would want to limit the size of each page (along with other criteria).

Another alternative (that is less of a CMS) may be **Jekyll**, where you can write pages in Markdown with a user-defined theme (there are many themes around for Jekyll and other static site generators). I've had success hosting this on CloudFlare Pages, which has a generous free tier and their CDN infrastructure performs really well.

You can also try [Netlify CMS](https://www.netlifycms.org/) which uses static site generators.

For example, this website that I've been hosting on CloudFlare Pages with Jekyll recieved a 100/100 score on desktop from PageSpeed Insights:

[image: PageSpeed Score]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link for Jekyll?

Answer (score 0):

You can get 100/100 pagespeed score out of the box with every CMS and Framework, including (but not limited to):

CMS:

- [TYPO3 CMS](https://typo3.org/)
- [Neos CMS](https://www.neos.io/)
- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/)
- [Plone CMS](https://plone.org/)

Static Page Generator:

- [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)

More a framework than a CMS:

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

It really is not a question about "what CMS should you use?", but about what template and what content you use. The moment you put your own content on your page, you have to consider optimizing for page speed - that's really the same in any CMS or Framework.